# Calligraphy translation assistance

Tags: translation, calligraphy

I would like assistance with translation of the text and seal,[image] if possible. I think it's written in Calligraphy.

Thannk you,
Stan

Answer (score 3):

It is a poem by a Qing Dynasty painter-calligrapher Huang Shen, who was known as one of the Eight Eccentrics of Yangzhou.

The poem is:

籃內河魚換酒錢，

蘆花被裏醉孤眠。

每逢風雨不歸去，

紅蓼灘頭泊釣船。

It basically discribes the life of a fisherman, who sells fish for money to buy wine and always stays with his boat despite the weather.

The signature is:

寧化黃慎

(Huang Shen from Ninghua)

The seal is:

果正

(Guozheng, born Wang Changshan, according to [this only source](http://www.rmyxw.net/news/show-2296.html), is a Buddist and a painter-calligrapher today)